# BiocManager::install("DiffBind") mergeOne.c:341:3: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code

Tags: r, bioconductor

I am using

```
BiocManager::install("DiffBind")
```

to install the package "DiffBind" on CentOS_7,
I got the error:

```
gcc -I"/opt/common/CentOS_7/R/R-4.0.5/lib64/R/include" -DNDEBUG -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -I'/lila/home/lid/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/Rhtslib/include' -I'/admin/opt/common/CentOS_7/R/R-4.0.5/lib64/R/library/Rcpp/include' -I/usr/local/include   -fpic  -g -O2  -c mergeOne.c -o mergeOne.o
mergeOne.c: In function ‘mungeTarget’:
mergeOne.c:341:3: error: ‘for’ loop initial declarations are only allowed in C99 mode
   for (int i=l;i<l+r;i++) {
   ^
mergeOne.c:341:3: note: use option -std=c99 or -std=gnu99 to compile your code
make: *** [mergeOne.o] Error 1
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘DiffBind’
```

Can anyone tell me what should I do?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a specific compiler in `~/.R/Makevars` file, create the folder and write it down in Makevers:

```
CC = gcc -std=c99
```

or:

```
CC = gcc -std=gnu99
```

Answer (score 3):

The previous answer is correct, in that the compiler wants to be able to use `C99` to compile your library.

However, the solution of putting `CC = gcc -std=c99` into your `~/.R/Makevars` is a little bit blunt, since **everything** that you now compile not directly from source is going to use the `-std=c99` flag. This is a recipe for some confusing and hard to track down error messages. It's a bit like installing everything in your base conda environment and waiting for everything to break.

It's a safer option to use `withr`, which allows you to specify compiler flags for individual installations, keeping everything nice and neat. It works a bit like the `with` (or `within`) function in R which constructs an environment to execute some command in.

```
library(withr)

with_makevars(
    c(PKG_CFLAGS = "-std=c99"), 
    BiocManager::install("DiffBind"), 
    assignment = "+="
)
```

It can also be performed directly with `BiocManager`:

```
BiocManager::install(
    "DiffBind", 
    configure.vars = c("CC" = "gcc", "-std" = "c99")
)
```

Comment: Couldn't that be done via the ... argument on `BiocManager::install` that it is passed to install.packages? `BiocManager::install("DiffBind", configure.vars = c("CC" = "gcc", "-std" = "c99")` never used it but I think this is the "standard" way.

Comment: @llrs ah, didn't realise that. Thanks, will add to answer!

Comment: I might be wrong. how the variables are passed but I think there is the option to do that via `install.packages` and by extension `BiocManager::install`